# How to specify Biztalk recievelocation document specification for multiple root elements

Tags: biztalk

I have a XSD with 15 root elements. The corresponding XML is received in one receivelocation with XML Validation on.

In current situation, I need to specify the 15 document spec, using the pipeline symbol "|" to seperate each other, which generate a very long string of document spec setting in receivelocation, like the following:

AAA.Common.Schemas.CIM.Ready.BBB+RegionalWeather, AAA.Common.Schemas, Version=1.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1234567890 | AAA.Common.Schemas.CIM.Ready.BBB+WeatherForcast, AAA.Common.Schemas, Version=1.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1234567890 | AAA.Common.Schemas.CIM.Ready.BBB+Typhoon, AAA.Common.Schemas, Version=1.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1234567890 | AAA.Common.Schemas.CIM.Ready.BBB+Flooding, AAA.Common.Schemas, Version=1.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1234567890 | ...

Is it possible to make the above long string documentspec simple? the ideal case is: AAA.Common.Schemas.CIM.Ready.BBB, AAA.Common.Schemas, Version=1.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1234567890

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your specific question, No.

However, this brings another question.  Why do you need to specify the document list in the Per-Instance config?

Unless you have duplicate MessageTypes, the XmlDisassembler will automatically resolve the DocumentSpec.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion (not specify document spec in the XMLValidate component). However, it says that "There was a failure executing the receive pipeline: "Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines.XMLReceive, Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Source: "XML disassembler" Receive Port: "FileReceivePort_CLP.PSI.ReceivePort/SOInfo" URI: "K:\temp\WIS_Input\*.xml" Reason: Validation can only be performed when document schemas are provided.  
"

Comment: Ok, since you're trying to Validate, what you need to do is create a Custom Pipeline with the XmlDisassembler and the XmlValidator components.  With that combination, you shouldn't have to specify the DocumentSpec anywhere.